# How to properly announce/perform an update of GitHub repo

Tags: git, github

Suppose there is a repository named Repo, and there have been some forks made from other people. Suppose Repo is some library or an API.

As people use the library/API, the owner continues development and in some time has added features and improved on the existing ones. What is the proper procedure of performing such an update? I am sure there is one that people abide by, that I am currently unaware of.

Should a separate branch always be made when implementing such updates? What is to be done, if one was unaware of that, and foolishly kept pushing the updates on the main branch?

Is there a way to inform the users (those who had forked/cloned repository) of the update?

I want to learn the established etiquette and procedures in play today and be compliant with them.

Comment: Do a versioning, introduce release cycle, tag from time to time.

Comment: Would you mind expanding your comment to an answer, I will accept it, as it gave me terms I can google and study on it.

Comment: Besides my laziness I don't think my comment is anyhow closer to the **good** answer. Basically you are asking for this part, and on other hand you would like to know how to setup process on your side. I would recommend to read something about `git flow`: http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be a complete and good answer to your question, but starting point of it will be that you will need to choose a git workflow.

I find the tutorial on Atlassian for this very useful.
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

One simple workflow that I know of (which atleast will fulfill the things that you want to do) is to use master/develop branch.

MASTER is your stable branch.
DEVELOP is your branch on which you add features.

When ever someone wants to work on a feature, he branches off develop. Does his changes and merges his change back to develop.

Something like this.

```
develop > git checkout -b featureX
featureX > touch README.md && git add . && git commit -m 'Add readme file'
featureX > git checkout develop
develop > git pull
develop > git checkout featureX
featureX > git rebase develop
featureX > git checkout develop
develop > git merge featureX
develop > git push origin develop
```

Along these lines many things happens. People can work simultaneously on different feature branches on their forked repo(in develop branch). When they do git rebase develop, they apply all the new commits ON TOP of their develop branch (git pull will always keep your HEAD recent).

Once you are some significant change you can mark the HEAD/or some commit as version using git tag. Then merge over all those changes into master

```
master> git merge develop
```

(This is when you release the next version of the product).

Of course while explaining all of this I might have missed many key points, but I would recommend reading the Atlassian tutorial at top and relying mostly on it than my answer here (that's from where I learned too).

There are some other git work flows too that allow for bug fixes, if in future you want to incorporate that too.

Answer (score 3):

By reading your question, I think this API is a open source project. So I'll tell you the normal procedure for handling contributors & versions.

First of all it's good to have a mailing list for all of your contributors. Now a days people use Google group as a mailing list. So all of your contributors can subscribe to that mailing list & you can send them message once.

The best practice to develop an open source project is,

- Don't commit to master directly
- Create separate branches for separate releases

You can develop the new features in a separate branch which is going to be in the master by the next release. When you finish implementing the feature & you are good to go with the release, merge that branch with the master branch & tag the master at that point by,

```
git tag v0.1.1
git push --tags
```

And also send a release note in the mailing list to notify the contributors that master is having new commits.

From that way other developers will not get confused & also tell them the next version of the API is going to develop in XXXXXXX branch. So when you create pull requests, create them to that XXXXXXX branch.

And also tell them to `rebase` their branch with your repository XXXXXXX branch before create the pull request

```
git pull --rebase upstream XXXXXXX
```

If you don't know how to add upstream,

```
git add remote upstream YOUR-REPO-URL
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the proper procedure of performing such an update?

The short, direct answer to your question is to use tags to mark official releases. For a longer answer, see [my own question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165725/git-branching-and-tagging-best-practices) on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)